# Extracting data as 'LOB' while querying thru Simba driver into MS SQL Server Integration Service(SSIS)?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have to extract data out of google-bigquery and load it to MS SQL server. I am using MS SSIS and used [Simba ODBC Driver](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/providers/simba-drivers/) to connect thru SSIS. its extracting data as LOB and hence converting it to row-by-row extract instead of batch processing and hence may be slowing the extraction process. Is there a way to extract data as regular character/int format?

Comment: what do you mean by 'LOB' here? is it about nested/repeated fields that are extracted as Json?

Comment: LOB stands for Large OBject, a stream of data stored in a database

Comment: I'm not sure how are doing this action. could you help us to clarify what type of data is used in BigQuery side, the commands used to extract the data  and how did you try to load into SQL Server?

Comment: I have the same trouble.. did you find someway to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I had been facing the same issue when i was trying to pull data From Google BigQuery to MS SQL!
What you are saying is absolutely correct, Because of the LOB columns the data that is getting Inserted is row by row rather than in a batch!
If you are using SIMBA , as you mentioned you are, then the simple fix to this issue would be to go your ODBC driver Settings (32 bit or 64 bit), select Google Bigquery DSN and then click on configure.
It will open SIMBA ODBC setup , then please go to your Advance Settings and You will find a Text box Input "Default String Column Length", this would be set to 16783 by default, you need to bring down the this length to somewhere say 200 Characters (Again it would depend on the highest length that a STRING data type column has in your case), and then you can click okay and test the connection.
This worked for me, as when i reduced the column length according to my requirement, it loaded the table without LOB and did it 15 times faster.

TIPS:

1. Re-Build the Connection Manager in SSIS after this OBDC configuration Changes
2. If you want to Check more details please turn on the SIMBA ODBC Trace logs and then run your package!
3. Try to TRIM Extra White Spaces if any, both trailing and leading in STRING Datatype column!

Hope This would help !
Thank you!